# JTextArea admin password control

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton

Very new and inexperienced coder, I'm currently working on my first 'from - scratch' project which will be a simple POS (Point Of Sale) restaurant till application.

The till has an admin panel which allows the user to change the menu presets and prices and will require a password to access it.

I am sloppy and using a lot imports as I am as I said very new.

Please take a look at the following:

```
if (source == passwordSubmit){
        if (logInPassword.getText() == adminPassword){
            loginFrame.setVisible(false);
            adminFrame.setVisible(true);    
        }
        else logInPassword.append("Incorrect");
    }
```

That code is within my `ActionListener` handler which lets the user enter text into the `JTextArea` called `logInPassword` and it compares the user text with the `adminPassword` preset string (currently set to `Password` as default)

But my code doesn't quite work... It's active as it gives me an "Incorrect" append into the `logInPassword` `JTextArea` but I'm typing in the correct password.

Do I need a getter or something?
Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `==` operator in Java, you are just comparing shallow reference values. The line `source == passwordSubmit` would work (since both should refer to the same object). However with strings, it is possible to have two string objects that equal the same in value. In that case, you have to do `logInPassword.getText().equals(adminPassword)` instead of `logInPassword.getText() == adminPassword`. The `equals` method compares by value of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

use .equals()

```
if (source == passwordSubmit){
            if (logInPassword.getText().equals(adminPassword){
                loginFrame.setVisible(false);
                adminFrame.setVisible(true);    
            }
            else logInPassword.append("Incorrect");
        }
```